# How to escape the new behavior for telephone numbers in html5

Tags: html

In an html5 document, how do I achieve the old html4 behavior?

i.e. I do not want this new behavior of it being clickable and having
any special text coloring, etc.

[I tried putting back-tics around the phone number, but that doesn't work.]

Is there some tag to put around text to shield it from getting special
treatment?

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9n2g4oou/ Maybe provide a little more context

Comment: Aha...yes, the <span> tag does exactly what I was looking for!